# Emphasize vs emphasize on

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Are these sentences correct?

1. Some schools emphasize physical education.
2. Some schools emphasize on physical education.
3. Some schools lay emphasis on physical education.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers 1 and 3 are fine. Number 2 is not idiomatic. **Emphasize** is a transitive verb and takes a direct object.